# How do I print a hexadecimal number with leading 0 to have width 2 using sprintf?

Tags: r, printf

I try to convert a number between 0 and 255 to hexadecimal format. If I use `sprintf("%X", 1)` I get `1`, but I need the output always to have width 2 (with leading 0s) instead of one. How can this be done?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use `%02X`:

```
sprintf("%02X",1)    # ->  "01"
sprintf("%02X",10)   # ->  "0A"
sprintf("%02X",16)   # ->  "10"
sprintf("%02X",255)  # ->  "FF"
```

Comment: With Ruby 2.1+,  sprintf("%02x",10)  -> "0a". Need to do a sprintf("%02X", 10) -> "0A" (note the capital 'X')

Comment: Oh right, I'm not sure this question is for ruby or any language I know. But perhaps your comment holds for more languages/versions and an edit is in order...